# What is the purpose of this code

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this code below, what is the purpose of `total = 0` and the line 5? This code should print 4 and 8 but it only returns 2!

```
def count_small(numbers):
    total = 0
    for n in numbers:
        if n < 10:
            total = total + 1
    return total


lost = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
small = count_small(lost)
print small
```

Comment: A StackOverflow question needs to include everything needed to answer it **in the question itself** (not behind an off-site link, and as text, not as an image). ("Please explain this code" questions are also often off-topic for other reasons -- ie. excessive scope/breadth -- but failing to have content included in the question proper is an immediate disqualifier regardless).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not include the code in the question.

Comment: Also, in general, you should use *either* the python-2.7 or the python-3.x tag, but not both at once. (If a question isn't version-specific, the python tag alone is adequate).

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't post links to images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on Meta StackOverflow.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new in stackoverflow and didn't get everything yet

Comment: If you need some time to read the rules and edit appropriately, if you delete your question, you can edit it while it's deleted and undelete it later.

Comment: With all due respect SO is a place where a lot of new programmers come for help. IMHO nit picking over tags and processes do not help bring the community forward. These things can be corrected with some guidance and patience. Please don't be so quick to down vote when a fellow dev is looking for some help.

Comment: Thanks @wickdninja , i was about to delete my account after reading these comments.

Comment: I'm sorry that you didn't feel welcome here. Charles wasn't trying to give you a hard time - he was trying to help you make your question better, so that it not only helps you, but so that it may help future readers as well.

Comment: @wickdninja, downvotes and close votes, and even deletes, are all reversible. It's not passing judgment on whether someone is welcome here, just indicating that their question isn't yet up-to-par and needs some editing and improvement. Our purpose here (the site's purpose *since its founding* -- Jeff's blog goes into depth there) is to build a high-quality knowledgebase -- that means caring about the quality of the questions as well as the answers. Helping folks with questions is a happy side effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy understood. The language I guess didn't feel friendly when I read it, hence why I felt the need to say something. I'm also fairly new to SO and I've had my share of "bad experiences" so I was more empathetic to Pythonic situation. No harm no foul though. :) Happy SO'ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns the count of the numbers that are smaller than 10. In your example 4 and 8 are below 10 so the count returned from your algorithm is 2, which is correct.

If you want to print out the numbers below 10 try this:

```
def print_small(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        if n < 10:
            print n

lost = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
print_small(lost)
```

Comment: `count_small` is not a method. It is a function.

Comment: Edited thanks. Syntax ok?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got it

Comment: Ok I'll correct the syntax when I get on my laptop later. @Pythonic if this solved your problem please accept as the answer & happy coding :)

Comment: I did but it took sometime ( peer review ) !

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Leave it to the (JS) & C# dev to mess up white space ;)